# Stay Safe Ukrainian Community Members - Reach out for help if needed

Tags: discussion

I know we have many Ukrainians that participate on this forum, if you are currently within any of the areas affected by the ongoing violence, I hope you are safe.

[@Mariia Illarionova](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/62973/mariia-illarionova)

[@Oleksandr Berehovskyi](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/22425/oleksandr-berehovskyi)

[@oleh-berehovskyi](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/60368/oleh-berehovskyi)

If you, or any family members need help once you are out of Ukraine (a place to stay, a temporary residence, food, anything) Feel free to reach out to me, I will do what I can. I have family and friends in Europe that are more than willing to help. I have family members that are currently trying to reach Poland and doing what I can to get them somewhere safe.

I should have posted this earlier, my apologies. Been going through so much in the past days, and didn't really think of others that might need help within the community.

Slava Ukraina!

(fyi - I understand if this post does not really belong here - feel free to delete or let me know if I should remove it)

Comment: I support. Not removing.

Comment: I also support this post, our Ukrainian community members, and the Russian citizens resisting the actions of their government.

Comment: Thank you guys for your support guys. I still do not believe that this is actually happening to us, while the whole world is supporting us and watching what is happening.

Comment: If there is anything I can help with - reach out, and I will see how I can assist.

Answer (score 16):

I always knew that only the best people are members of the salesforce community, those are sharing humanity values. @glls thank you for creating this topic here.

I want to say thank you to all who are supporting Ukrainians during this terrible time.  This help means a lot to us. We left our homes, we left our cities, our families are temporarily divided. A lot of men sent their wives, children abroad to a safer place. This support is needed for us.

For those, who are worried, I and my family are currently more or less safe. We left Kyiv at 6 a.m. on the first day of the war, the 24th of February. We are still in Ukraine.

Salesforce has already made a statement about Russian aggression and its further action [Standing with Ukraine](https://www.salesforce.com/news/stories/standing-with-ukraine/). A lot of appreciation from my personal side.

For community members from Ukraine. Stay safe. Move to a safe place. This is the most important action. Use your strong sides in this war. If you are a military professional - take a weapon and defend our land. If you are a good salesforce specialist - continue to work on projects. Continue to provide services for clients. They are supporting us, and this is our duty to continue providing good service. This will have a positive impact on our Ukrainian economy. We will pay taxes from abroad income. We will support our army. Use your strong sides.

For community members from the rest of the world. As a result of a report from March 6 "More than 360 civilians have been killed in Ukraine since Russia’s invasion began last month, the Office of the UN High Commissioner for Human Rights (OHCHR) said in a statement Sunday The total killed includes 74 men, 42 women, 8 boys, and 4 girls, as well as 13 children and 223 adults whose gender is not known. The total injured includes 67 men, 48 women, 11 girls, and 2 boys, as well as 28 children and 603 adults, per OHCHR.".

I beg you, don't do business with Russia, don't work on Russian clients. Our blood is on their hands.

We will win. No doubts here.

Slava Ukrayini (Glory to Ukraine)!

Comment: "We left Kyiv at 6 a.m. on the first day" =) Glad to hear you and your family are relatively safe. please keep us posted.